# Cobol: cannot find entry point of a text file

Tags: file-handling, cobol

Hi i am learning cobol from tutorialpoints and every program from there works as i've tested them in OpenCobolIDE(some needed a little editing). Then i came across the File Handling chapter and in there the program had a lot of errors. I did manage to rewrite the program until it didn't show me any errors but it doesn't do anything.

Here's my code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. HELLO.

       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
           INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
           FILE-CONTROL.
               SELECT STUDENT ASSIGN TO
               'C:\Cobol\FIle Handling\input.txt'
               ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
               ACCESS IS RANDOM
               RECORD KEY IS STUDENT-ID
               FILE STATUS IS FS.

       DATA DIVISION.
           FILE SECTION.
           FD STUDENT.
               01 STUDENT-FILE.
               05 STUDENT-ID PIC 9(5).
               05 NAME PIC A(25).

           WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
               01 WS-STUDENT-FILE.
               05 WS-STUDENT-ID PIC 9(5).
               05 WS-NAME PIC A(25).
               01 FS PIC 9(02).

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           OPEN I-O STUDENT.
               MOVE 20005 TO STUDENT-ID.
           READ STUDENT RECORD INTO WS-STUDENT-FILE
                   KEY IS STUDENT-ID
                   INVALID KEY DISPLAY 'Invalid Key'
                   NOT INVALID KEY DISPLAY WS-STUDENT-FILE
           END-READ.

           CLOSE STUDENT.
       STOP RUN.
```

This is the text file:

```
20003 Mohtashim M.
20004 Nishant Malik
20005 Amitabh Bachhan
```

The result should be the text:

```
20005 Amitabh Bachhan
```

Comment: Is the JCL set up correctly? My guess is that you are getting an error when trying to open the file. Either (according to the program) it doesn't exist or it is empty. Because this program has not checked any status codes, its impossible to tell. Add in some checks to see if the file is even opening.

Comment: @SaggingRufus it's OpenCOBOL (renamed years ago to GnuCOBOL). No JCL involved :-)

Comment: You can't just have a text file and use it as an indexed file. If you write another small COBOL program to create your indexed file (input the existing file, WRITE each record to the indexed file) and assuming you have "indexed file support" installed, then your program above needs to be changed to reference the new indexed file, and then should work. You almost certainly got a non-zero FILE STATUS on the OPEN, and the READ, as @SaggingRufus already suggested . It's good to indicate on the READ that you are doing a keyed access.

Answer (score 2):

It's doing something: It's reading the file.  But that's all; you didn't ask for it to display or do anything else beyond reading the record into memory.  You might want to look at using the DISPLAY statement or maybe create another file to write the output to.

Might I make a couple of suggestions?

In modern COBOL, stylistically, you don't put a period after everything in the procedure division -- you only put it in where it is necessary.  For example:

```
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       OPEN I-O STUDENT
       MOVE 20005 TO STUDENT-ID
       READ STUDENT RECORD INTO WS-STUDENT-FILE
          KEY IS STUDENT-ID
          INVALID KEY DISPLAY 'Invalid Key'
          NOT INVALID KEY DISPLAY WS-STUDENT-FILE
       END-READ

       CLOSE STUDENT
       STOP RUN
       .
```

Although the compiler doesn't care about spaces and returns, if I were you, I'd try to indent my code a bit better (I like how I indented the above :-) ). It's up to you and a lot of people like to do it differently, but if you are consistent you can spot problems that might sneak through your code.

**Edit:** I didn't notice that you were reading with a key from a text file.  So, either you need to:

1. read from a pre-built indexed file, or
2. read the file sequentially and search for what you want by comparing what you read for the student id you wanted.

Comment: How could it be reading the file properly? It's a textfile so it would not be indexed. OP is doing an indexed lookup.

Comment: @SaggingRufus You're right; I read things too quickly and didn't notice it was a text file.